# What kind of loss is it?

Tags: autoencoder, loss-function

I check this file (
https://github.com/saman-nia/Deep-Neural-Networks-for-Clustering/blob/master/Iris%20dataset/Autoencoder%20on%20iris%20dataset.ipynb) and found that the loss function:

```
def loss(reconstructed, x):
    with tf.variable_scope("train"):
        train_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(reconstructed, x)), 1))
        return train_loss
```

I wonder what kind of this loss function or it is just an invented loss? Thank you!

Comment: This would seem to be the mean squared error.

Comment: @Tyberius: It looks like   ((re - x )^2 + 1)/N but why we need to add 1? MSE does not have this??

Comment: It means they're doing the reduce_sum on the 1st axis. They're not adding 1 to the tensor.